# Install SQL CLR types & Report Viewer 2012 on Sql 2008 server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs, sqlclr

I'm in the process of installing a client's ASP.net site on a Windows Server 2003 box running Sql 2008.

The site uses Report Viewer 2012, but when I attempted to install it on the server, I got the message "CLR Types for Sql Server 2012" were missing.

Does anyone know if it be possible to install the 2012 CLR types alongside SQL 2008, and without Sql 2012?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

“Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012” can be downloaded at [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) (direct links: [X86 version](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239643&clcid=0x409), [X64 version](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239644&clcid=0x409)).

And it seems to have fixed the installation problem for us; the server we needed to install the Report Viewer 2012 on does not have SQL Server installed at all.

Comment: +1 for the direct links. they seem impossible to find using microsoft's search tools.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like these links are now dead, I posted a new answer with an updated link if anyone is still looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

**Here the solution to download the Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012**

**Step 1 :** Choose the below website link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065

**Step 2 :** In this link, you have to choose the "Install instructions" menu.                                                                 Then, you need to troll down up to you have seen the content mentioned below.

Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012
The SQL Server System CLR Types package contains the components implementing the geometry, geography, and hierarchy id types in SQL Server 2012. This component can be installed separately from the server to allow client applications to use these types outside of the server.

Note: This component also requires Windows Installer 4.5
X86 Package(SQLSysClrTypes.msi)
X64 Package (SQLSysClrTypes.msi)

**STEP 3 :** You may download the file as you needed, along with these software if you're looking for

Microsoft report viewer 2012, you follow this below website link to download it.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747

**Regards**,

**Hem Shankar**

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the first link is now dead, I posted a new answer with an updated link if anyone is still looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

We've managed to work around this issue by using Report Viewer 2010 in the ASP.net application.

Sadly I'm no wiser about whether 2012 CLR types can be installed alongside a SQL 2008 installation, but after reading their requirements more carefully, I did see that they require a later OS than Server 2003 anyway, so I wouldn't be able to install them in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the above links are now dead.  I was able to find the CLR types at the following link for [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 SP4 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56041)

Click `Download` and then scroll down and locate `SQLSysClrTypes.msi` (I just chose the larger download).  Install `SQLSysClrTypes.msi` and then install `ReportViewer.msi` and it should work.